# Unity batchmode open command line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cmd

I struggle a bit with opening a command prompt from c# in a Unity script. I want to achieve that I can open the built .exe with -batchmode and / or -nographics an that the only thing visible is the command prompt where you can enter commands.

It has only to work in windows since this project is supposed to run as a dedicated game server.

Can anyone give me a hint how to achieve this??

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what are you trying to do. Do you want to build a Unity project that will run in the command line without opening a window? Or do you want to "open" a prompt from C#, whatever this means?

Comment: Both are ok i guess... if I use -batchmode and -nographics there will be nothing visible and the "game" be running. But to be able to give any orders for example starting the server or shuting him down I figured a simple command prompt would be the easiest... I was not able to just open a prompt from C#. So maby it is easier run in command line. But how is it possible to manage the inputs in c# from the command line after the start?

Comment: So, by "opening the command prompt" you mean having a console-based user interface?

Comment: Yes, as long the user interface is not built in unity :)